# Flatpak hub OS updates

Tags: updates, snap, repository, flatpak

Hi there I installed the flatpak hub and repository but it offered an OS update that i installed however the default Ubuntu repository did not offer this OS update

Why did the flatpak repository offer this but the default ubuntu one did not? and was it safe to install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Please explain what you exactly mean by "OS update". The operating system = Ubuntu itself cannot be update via Flatpak. Flatpak is for application software only.

Comment: Without details, you are asking us to speculate.

Comment: it had an option at the top that was underlined as "os update" in the update section of the flatpak hub

Comment: Most be somtehing else - technically it is impossible that Flatpak updates your Ubuntu system.

Comment: ok I'm not describing it well and I'm not sure if you can post pictures but does the gnome software app mean anything?

Comment: Gnome Software can do system update (see [documentation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/blob/main/doc/use-cases.md)), although it is not the primary task of Gnome Software. However, this is not related to whether Flatpak is activated in Gnome Software or not.

Comment: yeah I think if was the gnome software that pushed an update even if the default Ubuntu software app did not